# Make element not occupy any space

Tags: html, css

I want to create a diagonal bar that is displayed over some elements and not others on the page (see fig 1).

[image: Fig 1]

Fig 1

I try to do this by something like

```
#diagonal-bar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150%;
    -*-transform: rotate(10deg);
}

.over {
    z-index: ..
}

.under {
    z-index: ..
}
```

My inner vision is for the page to look like fig 2, that is, the diagonal bar extends beyond the page but it gets "cropped" away. The result is instead that, because of the `position: absolute;` property, the `body` element extends to the height of the `#diagonal-bar` like in fig 3. Is there some way to make an element have an element not occupy any space, even though it is there? Some kind of mixture between the `fixed` and `absolute` position property.

Adding `body { overflow: hidden; }` is not an option I'm afraid, as the page becomes un-scrollable. I know I could hack something together with jQuery, but if possible I would prefer a solution with html and css.

[image]

Fig 2

[image]

Fig 3

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you try `#diagonal-bar {top: -25%; overflow-y: hidden;}` ?

Comment: I tried it, but nothing else happens. As the `#diagonal-bar` contains no children, the `overflow-y: hidden;` will not do anything right? Adding it to the parent `body` is as stated not an option as I need the page to be scrollable.

Comment: So... you could try something like: `#parent-of-diagonal-bar {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:10; width:100%; height:100%; overflow-y: hidden;}` and then inside that, `#diagonal-bar {top: -25%;}` (Admittedly, this is just something to try off the top my head)

Comment: @Rounin Cheers for input! When having the parent `fixed`, the `body` does not expand, which is really nice. However, it is fixed to the viewport and not the document, and so the diagonal bar "follows" when scrolling (i.e. it is fixed on the screen when scrolling). Ideally I would want some combination of absolute and fixed positioning: absolute in the sense that it is stationary with respect to the document, but fixed in the sense that its size does not affect the rest of the document at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `position`ing the container `absolute`ly?

eg. https://jsfiddle.net/0xv7vygd/

Comment: Yeah I've tried that as well. The problem is that I have found no possible way of using the `overflow: hidden;` property of the container as the page needs to be scrollable (i.e. the container needs an `overflow-y: scroll` property to allow for scrolling).

Comment: But the container, doesn't need to be `body {...}`, right? You can have `<div id="screen">` as the child of `<body>` and the parent of `<div id="diagonal-bar">`, no?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. As @Rounin said, you can just wrap the element in a container of some kind; or else, if you just want it to run off the edge of the page, it should still work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/0xv7vygd/2/embedded/result/

Comment: It was a while ago I asked this question, but I realize that after some tweaking the solution was to position it absolutely.